# nginx ingress TCP port Enable Sticky based routing

Tags: load-balancing, nginx-ingress

By using below ConfigMap and Deployment i am able to enable row tcp connecting in nginx ingress

### ConfigMap.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-basic
data:
  65432: "default/tis-platform:65432"
```

### Deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
    ...
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.9.5
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle: 
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                - /wait-shutdown
          args: 
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/my-ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=my-ingress-nginx-leader
            - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/my-ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
            - --tcp-services-configmap=ingress-basic/tcp-services
```

Right now it's working based on Round Robin, how can i implement nginx other Load Balancing Algorithms for above case?

Right now it's working based on Round Robin, how can I implement nginx other Load Balancing Algorithms for the above case?